# Material-UI datetime picker calendar doesn't show 6th week

Tags: material-ui

If the month has 31 days in 6 rows, the last row of dates is hidden and is not compiling in DOM. 
Looks like the code missed the 6th line of dates anywhere. It happens with all the months covering 6 weeks. 
Any tips? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, I updated the utils on `<MuiPickersUtilsProvider />`.